# VMware or Virtual Box! Cannot install Opensource OS

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I cannot install ubuntu/linux or Windows OS in Vmware/Virtual Box in Windows 7 host. I had used these before on my Windows 7 32 bit OS. Recently I formatted all the drives (Clean Format) and installed Windows 7 same version. The error show no virtualization supported. VT-x is not supported. I cannot see the virtualization enable option in boot menu also. Both Upgraded versions are not working, So had to choose the lower version where Virtualization supported earlier

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Yes but I cannot install the OS anymore. shows up virtualization not supported. any other ways to install Linux

Comment: IIRC VT-x support is an option in your BIOS. @Ramhound IIRC VT-x is necessary if you want to assign more than one processor to the VM.

Comment: I meant "core"...

Comment: @xenoid - There is a huge difference between the configuration of a virtual machine that supports multiple processors and one that uses multiple cores. However, even if you meant cores instead of processors I still don't agree with that statement.  I have personally used VMWare with VT-x disabled, ran a 32-bit guest OS within that virtual machine, and assigned multiple cores to that virtual machine.

Comment: @ramhound See https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch10.html#hwvirt . How should we read: *VirtualBox's 64-bit guest support (added with version 2.0) and multiprocessing (SMP, added with version 3.0) both require hardware virtualization to be enabled.* So you are right in the now rare case of 32-bit OSes. All processors designed after 2006 (Intel and AMD) support hardware virtualization. However on recent Intel there are Hyper-V and VT-x and they are mutually exclusive (and recent Windows enables Hyper-V by default it seems) .

Comment: **multiprocessing** means multiple processors it does not mean a processor with multiple cores.  I also never said VT-x wasn't required for a 64-bit guest OS, I just said it wasn't required for a 32-bit guest OS, which appears I took as an implied statement.

Answer (score 0):

> Laptop : Compaq CQ40-414 TU

Based on the information you provided I concluded you must have the following processor.

> T7350, 2.00-GHz, 3-MB L2 cache, 1066-MHz FSB

[Compaq Presario CQ40 Notebook PC Maintenance and Service Guide](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01531211.pdf)

The `Intel® Core™2 Duo Processor P7350` of course does not support VT-x based on it's specifications.

> Intel® Virtualization Technology (VT-x) - No

[Intel® Core™2 Duo Processor P7350](https://ark.intel.com/products/36750/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-P7350-3M-Cache-2_00-GHz-1066-MHz-FSB)

I conclude that based on the fact you cannot enable hardware virtualization (VT-x) due to the option not appearing in your laptop's firmware configuration you either have a processor that does not support VT-x or your motherboard's firmware is restricted in such a way it cannot be enabled.

> I cannot see the virtualization enable option in boot menu also.
>
> I cannot install Ubuntu or Windows within VMware/VirtualBox virtual
>   machine running on a Windows 7 host.

Based on the information you provided, you **should be able** to run a 32-bit version of either Ubuntu or Windows, within your virtual machine running on a 32-bit host OS.

Based on the information you provided you will be **unable** to run a 64-bit operating system within a virtual machine running on a 32-bit host OS.  Your hardware based on my research, and the information you provided, the hardware you are using does not support it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed analysis. But I recently had to erase all my files and formatted my hard disk(full format, I deleted all the drives) after that I cannot install any of the ubuntu version or windows 10.

Comment: Previously I had no issues with the installation by using the same ISO in VMware or Virtual Box before formatting. Now it shows VT-x not supported.

Comment: Only ubuntu version (12 to 17) is getting the error. Windows 7 works fine in Virtual box. In Ubuntu the error I get is *THIS KERNEL REQUIRES AN X86-64 CPU, BUT ONLY DETECTED AN i686 CPU. UNABLE TO BOOT - PLEASE USE A KERNEL APPROPRIATE FOR YOUR CPU